# Firestore or Provider giving back old data flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

I am using cloud_firestore and riverpod in my project.
I have a firestore database with some data. If I delete the data in firestore, I would expected my app to notice that as well. But at first I get the old data.

```
@riverpod
Option<MyObject> closeObjectLocation(CloseObjectLocationRef ref) {
  final objects = ref.watch(objectsWithinRadiusProvider
      .select((value) => value.valueOrNull));

  debugPrint("objects count: ${objects?.length}");

}
```

The logs looks as follows:

```
objects count: null
objects count: 1
objects count: 0
```

It leads to wrong behaviours within the app.

There many layers between the provider and firestore.

```
@riverpod
Stream<List<Object>> objectsWithinRadius(ObjectsWithinRadiusRef 
ref) {
  final myLocation =
  ref.watch(positionStreamProvider.select((value) => 
    value.valueOrNull));
  final objectsStream = ref
  .watch(objectsWithinRadiusRepoProvider(
  myLocation!.latitude, myLocation.longitude))
  .getObjects();

  return objectsStream;
}
```

Here the firestore stream.

```
Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> collectionStreamWithRadius({
required String path,
required double radius,
required String field,
required GeoFirePoint center,
  }) {
    return _streamErrorHandler(
      () {
        var reference = geoFlutterFire
            .collection(collectionRef: 
        firebaseFirestore.collection(path))
        .within(
          center: center,
          radius: radius,
          field: field,
          strictMode: true,
        );

    return reference;
  },
 );
}
```

Basically I want to invalidate the cache when I close the app such that it fetches new values gain and not the cache one.

Comment: Can you show the code for `objectsWithinRadius` provider?

Comment: Need to know what's inside `objectsWithinRadius` provider, because that's the one provider that's triggering a rebuild of `closeObjectLocation` provider

Comment: Hmm that's a lot of provider dependencies. You have to track down which provider caused the rebuild on each of the output that you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the solution was pretty easy, in hindsight. I just had to disable firestore offline support.

```
final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
firestore.settings = const Settings(persistenceEnabled: false);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Option<MyObject> closeObjectLocation(CloseObjectLocationRef ref) {
  final objects = ref.list(objectsWithinRadiusProvider, (previous, next) {

    debugPrint("objects count: $next");
  }
 
}
```

i think the cuse is that as in start the stream is not passing any data, as the result variable is null.

Comment: I still run into the block `data: (data) {` twice.

Comment: i could not figure out the exact cause but meanwhile i added the if else block that should just work.

Comment: can you confirm that `myLocation` is non-null ? use `if (myLocation == null) {
    //  myLocation is null
    
  }else{//it is not null   }`

Comment: As you can see in the  questtion from logs, I am getting null (when loading) once then 1 and 0. I would like to skip the 1 and only get 0. The problem is not null but the fact that I get 1, which is no longer accurate as I have deleted the data in firestore and at last 0 which is the value I am interested in.

Comment: check if the list works?

Comment: it does not work. Basically I want to invalidate the cache when I close the app such that if fetches new values gain and not the cache one.